# Should i bind my service or call startService multiple times?

Tags: java, android, service, android-service-binding

I send data between my activity and my service through an intent ( i call startForegroundService multiple times because this call onStartCommand again and with getIntent i fetch my data).

**Example:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MediaPlayerService.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("songList", Main.musicList);
intent.putExtra("songIndex", position);
intent.setAction(Constants.ACTIONS.ACTION_PLAY);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getActivity(), intent);
```

I read somewhere it's better to communicate with my service through binding.

But i'm achieving the same thing with this method, so which one is preferable?

Comment: its not black and white to say its "better" to use service bindings. Its has some particular usecases. I would recommend reading the docs about service communication - they are pretty extensive.

Comment: @JoxTraex But if i only want to send data between my activities and my service, is my method right?

Comment: Yes, as @pskink said, binding service is the way to go if you want to communicate between your service and activity

Comment: @pskink Only data i want to send to my service is an Arraylist and a position in my arraylist so should i still opt for binding my service?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs :

> Started
>
> A service is "started" when an application component (such as an
>   activity) starts it by calling startService(). Once started, a service
>   can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that
>   started it is destroyed. Usually, a started service performs a single
>   operation and does not return a result to the caller. For example, it
>   might download or upload a file over the network. When the operation
>   is done, the service should stop itself.
>
> Bound
>
> A service is "bound" when an application component binds to it by
>   calling bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server
>   interface that allows components to interact with the service, send
>   requests, get results, and even do so across processes with
>   interprocess communication (IPC). A bound service runs only as long as
>   another application component is bound to it. Multiple components can
>   bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service
>   is destroyed.

You can read more about this @ : [Android Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)